# Setting hidden default for jQuery toggle

Tags: jquery, toggle

I'm using simple jQuery toggle method:

```
$('fieldset').click(function () {
    $('fieldset>ul').toggle("slow");
});
```

Is there any way ul would be hide by default ?

One option would be setting `style="display:none"` on the `ul` tag , But it's not possible for me !

Is there any other way ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will hide all ULs when the DOM is loaded

```
$(function(){$('fieldset>ul').hide();})
```

Answer (score 2):

**Use `$('fieldset>ul').hide()` for hiding ul.**

Answer (score 1):

on top of code add:
    `$('fieldset').find('ul').css({'display': 'none'})`

Answer (score 0):

just add `$('fieldset>ul').hide();`on top of the

```
$('fieldset').click(function () {
    $('fieldset>ul').toggle("slow");
});
```